# Incorrect (strings) shaped values in timestamp column, how can I handle with this in SQL or python?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I want some advice about this problem.
I have table in SQL database with stream data. I read this data in Python and I analyze it.

But in my table, there are some incorrect shaped/typed values/observations in my `DataSet`. One of the problems is strings in the timestamp column. (there is something like `aaaaaaa` in `DateTime` column)
(Actually, I know this writing string should not be allowed but this is a test process and we can't change the format of the columns right now)

How can I clear this in my database in the simplest way?
(Delete query in SQL is not an option now because my live dashboard could take the data incorrect typed data anyway).

I'm adding '...`WHERE LEN(Time_) > 15`....' for now and it works well but I think if there could exist a better solution? For now, there is no problem but someone could write a string into timestamp columns with higher character :/

Edit: I created a new view and change the column like this, TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, Time_) AS Time_ and it works well.

Comment: Not clear why a SQL delete isn't viable - can you clarify, please?

Comment: Actually, it is working clear but data come to db in every minute more than 20 times. So if new value would be incorrect shape (like 'aaaaa' or 'xxxxxx') my application tries to take this as DATE and it'll be cracked. Actually i see, this not looks logical but there is a issue like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the try: function in Python and try to convert the string into a datetime object. If it fails you disregard it.

Something like this:

```
import datetime as dt
datetime_list = []
for value in list_of_values:
    try:
        datevalue = dt.strptime(value,'%Y-%m-%d') # change the dateformat of the string here if it is not YYYY-MM-DD
        datetime_list.append(datevalue)
    except:
        print('could not convert this value: ',value)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but this is kinda slow for large shaped dataset.

Answer (score 0):

> Not clear why a SQL delete isn't viable - can you clarify, please?

> Actually, it is working clear but data come to db in every minute more than 20 times. So if new value would be incorrect shape (like 'aaaaa' or 'xxxxxx') my application tries to take this as DATE and it'll be cracked. Actually i see, this not looks logical but there is a issue like this

So instead of `DELETE` you can just filter out items in SQL using a `WHERE` clause.

I think creating a `VIEW` object is a good idea for this, so you don't have to think about things nearly as much!

Instead of using `Len("Time_")` as the check, which is not sufficient, I'll perform a couple of other checks with an aim to:

1. Be more accurate (testing for a `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM` format)
2. Be more efficient (the `LIKE` comparison here should be sargable given appropriate indexing)
3. Returns a `datetime` value for `Time_`

```sql
CREATE VIEW my_schema.valid_my_data
SELECT explicit
     , list
     , of
     , columns
     , including
     , Try_Convert(datetime, "Time_", 120) AS "Time_"
FROM   my_schema.all_my_data
WHERE  "Time_" LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9] [0-2][0-9]:[0-6][0-9]'
AND    Try_Convert(datetime, "Time_", 120) IS NOT NULL
;
```

### Bonus Points

If the invalid data is never needed - you should still delete it periodically. No point in keeping duff data kicking about.

Check the execution plan of the query in the view to ensure it's reasonably optimal. An index on `Time_` would probably help.

Add any other data validation logic and type conversion in the view directly.

I was going to suggest making this in to an [indexed view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15), but I'm not sure if the string-to-datetime conversion would be supported. So I guess bonus points for if you at least try that.